# How to initialize a 2D-array in GMP?

Tags: c, arrays, gmp

I'm trying to create a 2D-array that contains GMP integers in C, but I don't find any good documentation for this on the Internet, so I tried to generalize the way a 1D-array should be initialized without success. The following code gives me a segmentation fault.

```
mpz_t array[num1][num2];

for (int i=0; i<num1; ++i){
   for (int j=0; j<num2; ++j){
      mpz_init (array[i][j]);
   }
}
```

How should this be done?

Comment: What are the values of  num1 and num2?

Comment: Looks quite alright to me. https://github.com/PICCO-Team/picco/blob/master/compiler/src/utility/utility.cpp#L255 Can you indeed isolate the error? Does it fail if this is the only thing you do in your `main` function?